# KeyError on FeatureUnion between TfDif and custom features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to create a model where I'll use TfidfVectorizer on a text column and also a couple of other columns with extra data on the text. The code below reproduces what I'm trying to do and the error I get.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB

class ParStats(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        print(X[0])
        return [{'feat_1': x['feat_1'],
                 'feat_2': x['feat_2']}
                for x in X]

class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, data_dict):
        return data_dict[self.key]

def feature_union_test():

    # create test data frame
    test_data = {
        'text': ['And the silken, sad, uncertain rustling of each purple curtain',
                 'Thrilled me filled me with fantastic terrors never felt before',
                 'So that now, to still the beating of my heart, I stood repeating',
                 'Tis some visitor entreating entrance at my chamber door',
                 'Some late visitor entreating entrance at my chamber door',
                 'This it is and nothing more'],
        'feat_1': [4, 7, 10, 7, 4, 6],
        'feat_2': [1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 10],
        'ignore': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
    }
    test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=test_data)
    y_train = test_df['ignore'].values.astype('int')

    # Feature Union Pipeline
    pipeline = FeatureUnion([

                ('text', Pipeline([
                    ('selector', ItemSelector(key='text')),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5)),
                ])),

                ('parstats', Pipeline([
                    ('stats', ParStats()),
                    ('vect', DictVectorizer()),
                ]))

            ])

    tfidf = pipeline.fit_transform(test_df)

    # fits Naive Bayes
    clf = BernoulliNB().fit(tfidf, y_train)

feature_union_test()
```

When I run this, I get the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rogerio\Python VENV\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3064, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

I've tried several different iterations of the pipeline and I always get some sort of error, so obviously I'm missing something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just as you have added ItemSelector in first part of the pipeline, why have you not added the same to second part (`ParStats`)? Whats `X[0]`? If X is a dataframe, then does it have a column named `0` in it? Or do you want to print the first row of dataframe?

Comment: Also DictVectorizer just arranges the data in list of dicts to separate features (according to keys in dicts). But you have already separate data into columns (feat_1 and feat_2). So I am not sure why you are using DictVectorizer?

Comment: @VivekKumar The print(X[0]) was part of my debugging and I should have removed it before posting the question. DictVectorizer converts the dictionary that the transform returns into a matrix to be used in sklearn.

Comment: Thats what I am saying. Does your columns `feat1` and `feat2` contain dictionaries as elements? Can you show some samples of it?

Comment: `feat1` and `feat2` contain only integers. The Full `dataframe` is in the code. However transform returns a dictionary.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I am talking about the part under that. Transform returns a dictionary all right, but then the DictVectorizer will again convert that dict into two columns. So what I am asking is why are you using this, when in the end your data dont change.

Comment: If I could pass the pandas dataframe directly to the pipeline, I wouldn't need the ParStats or the DictVectorizer. But I don't know how I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So after discussion in comments, this is your problem statement.

> You want to pass the columns `feat_1`, `feat_2` along with the tfidf of `text` column to your ml model.

So the only thing you need to do is this:

```
# Feature Union Pipeline
pipeline = FeatureUnion([('text', Pipeline([('selector', ItemSelector(key='text')),
                                            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5)),
                                           ])),
                         ('non_text', ItemSelector(key=['feat_1', 'feat_2']))
                        ])

tfidf = pipeline.fit_transform(test_df)
```

The default `ItemSelector` can be used to select multiple features at once which will be appended to the last of the tfidf data return from `text` part of feature Union.

Comment: This is actually an even simpler solution than the one proposed by @Qusai Alothman above, therefore I'm marking this as the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs in `transform` in your `ParStats` class.

First of all, `pandas` doesn't support indexing directly, so your `print(X[0])` is throwing the error you saw.

And you can't iterate a `pandas` DataFrame in the way you are doing it.

Here is a possible working version of the function:

```
def transform(self, X):
    return [{'feat_1': x[0], 'feat_2': x[1]} 
            for x in X[['feat_1', 'feat_2']].values]
```

Of course, there are a lot of other possible solutions, but you get the idea.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!! The issue was with my usage of Pandas and not FeatureUnion as I suspected. The print(X[0]) I left there by mistake It was part of my debugging.